# Passing dictionary values as constructor's arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie to Python. I need to create a simple student class which includes first name, last name, id, and a dictionary which maps course name to its grade.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, id, _____ (dictionary values)):
        self._firstName = firstName;
        self._lastName = lastName;
        self._id = id;

        self.
```

My question is how can I initizalize the dictionary values inside the constructor?

For example, let`s say I would like to add 3 course to grade mappings: 
"math: 100"
"bio: 90"
"history: 80"

For example:

```
student1 = Student("Edward", "Gates", "0456789", math: 100, bio: 90, history: 80)
```

The last 3 values should go into the dictionary.

Since the number of key-value which can be part of the dictionary can vary, what should I write in the constructor parameter signature?

I want to send all the student values when I call the constructor...

Comment: You can just take in a single dictionary variable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are looking to add a dictionary Mathias' answer suffices with the [key word arguments](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html) in python.

However, if you wish to add object variables from the key word arguments, you require [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

For example, if you want something like this:

```
student1 = Student("Edward", "Gates", "0456789", {'math': 100, 'bio': 90, 'history': 80})
print student1.math #prints 100
print student1.bio  #prints 90
```

Then this will do the trick:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, id, **kwargs):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.id = id
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, key, value)

student1 = Student("Edward", "Gates", "0456789", {'math': 100, 'bio': 90, 'history': 80})
```

Note that ****kwargs** will unpack only something like dictionary or tuple of tuples. If you wish to send a list of values without keys, you should use ***args**. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html) to know more.

Comment: When I try the same command, I get this error: ""TypeError: Student.__init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given"" Why?

Answer (score 2):

Python collects all keyword arguments for you.

```python
class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, id, **kwargs):
        self._firstName = firstName;
        self._lastName = lastName;
        self._id = id;

        self. _grades = kwargs
```

[Here is an excellent explanation about kwargs in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Why not send the complete grades dictionary to the your class and store it in a variable.
(Also please note that in Python there is no semicolon at the end of the line)

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, id, grade_dict):
        self._firstName = firstName
        self._lastName = lastName
        self._id = id
        self._grades = grade_dict

    def get_grades(self):
        return self._grades
```

and then when you want to initialize and use the grades:

```
student1 = Student("Edward", "Gates", "0456789", {'math': 100, 'bio': 90, 'history': 80})
grades = student1.get_grades()
for key, value in grades.items():
    print 'Marks in {}: {}'.format(key, str(value))
```

Which prints:

```
Marks in bio: 90
Marks in math: 100
Marks in history: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
student = Student("Edward", "Gates", "0456789", {"math": 100, "bio": 90, "history": 80})
```

And inside your constructor you can copy these values to a new dictionary:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, id, grades):
        self._firstName = firstName;
        self._lastName = lastName;
        self._id = id;

        self._grades = grades.copy()
```

Notice that we're copying the dictionary to a new attribute because we want to avoid keeping a reference.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to remove the semicolon `;` from your code - it won't compile!
Second, I believe you're looking to do something like:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, _id, **courses):
        self._first_name = first_name
        self._last_name = last_name
        self._id = _id
        self.courses = courses

    def print_student(self):
        print self._first_name
        print self._last_name
        print self._id
        for key in self.courses:
            print key, self.courses[key]


courses = {'math': 100, 'bio': 90, 'history': 80}    
s = Student("John", "Smith", 5, **courses)
s.print_student()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
John
Smith
5
bio 90
math 100
history 80
```